# Please stop throwing away my custom close reason on error

Tags: feature-request, bug, vote-to-close, custom-close-reasons

Maybe I don't have the most reliable connection, or maybe this is a problem on Stack Exchange's side or somewhere in the middle.

But the bottom line is that my custom close reason often gets discarded due to "an error", which is quite irritating.

At this stage I'm contemplating just copying the reason each time before clicking close, just in case it gets discarded.

**To reproduce:**

- Open the close dialog on a question.
- Disable your network connection (unplug your network cable and/or turn off Wi-Fi).
- Enter a custom close reason and vote to close.
- Get the "I'm sorry, I didn't catch that, can you repeat it?" error.

  [image]

**Suggested fix:**

Leave the dialog open when an error occurs (or have any custom reason persist through multiple opens of the dialog).

It also wouldn't hurt to try a little harder to submit that close vote.

Comment: Another option is to not create a new dialog on each click on "close", but rather use the same instance.

Comment: Also, I think there's a glitch on mobile where it sometimes says "close reason already used" when there are no close votes when you use a custom close vote.